# jqgrid - Add new row and disable restoreRow function

Tags: jqgrid

If I will add new row and I will enable automatic editing newly added row, then I want to perform validation and save row by ENTER button, BUT I don't want to restore row by ESC button. Because I set `required: true` by all fields and If newly added row will be to have empty at least one field, then ESC button (`restoreRow`) causes inconsistency my data, because will not be performed validation and newly added row will be to have empty fields. Although I set `required: true`.

The problem is that After added new row I always want to validate the edited row before saving, but ESC button causes restoreRow. **For normal editing causes by doubliClick I want use ESC for restore row and ENTER for save row.**

**My code is generated from coffeescript**

```
$("#add-row").click((function(_this) {
  return function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return _this.saveEditingRow(function() {
      var dataIds;
      _this.table.jqGrid("addRowData", void 0, "last");
      dataIds = _this.table.jqGrid("getDataIDs");
      if (dataIds.length > 0) {
        return _this.table.jqGrid("editRow", dataIds[dataIds.length - 1], {
          keys: true,
          url: "clientArray",
          aftersavefunc: function(rowId) {
            return retypeColumnValues.call(table, rowId);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  };
})(this));


Table.prototype.saveEditingRow = function(successfunc, errorfunc) {
    var i, result, savedRows, success, _i, _ref;
    savedRows = this.table.jqGrid("getGridParam", "savedRow");
    success = true;
    for (i = _i = 0, _ref = savedRows.length; _i < _ref; i = _i += 1) {
      if (savedRows.length > 0) {
        result = this.table.jqGrid("saveRow", savedRows[i].id, {
          url: "clientArray"
        });
        if (!result && success) {
          success = false;
        }
      }
    }
    if (success) {
      return typeof successfunc === "function" ? successfunc() : void 0;
    } else {
      return typeof errorfunc === "function" ? errorfunc() : void 0;
    }
};
```

If it will be necessary, I will fill all code in coffeescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that it's a problem because the option `keys: true` register `keydown` event handler which process **both** <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Esc</kbd>. You can't just inform jqGrid to process <kbd>Enter</kbd>, but don't process <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

If you don't call `restoreRow` in your code then you could probably salve your problem by usage of  `beforeCancelRow` callback which you could define in `$.jgrid.inlineEdit`.

```js
$.extend(true, $.jgrid.inlineEdit, {
    beforeCancelRow: function () { // the parameters options and rowid can be used
        return false;
    }
});
```

The code above will don't allows `restoreRow` at all. You can modify the code by including some validations.

One more options which you have: don't use `keys: true`, but register your own `keydown` handler on all `<input>` and `<select>` fields in the editing row. You can do this inside of `oneditfunc` callback. See [the source code](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.7.0/js/grid.inlinedit.js#L112-L134) of `keydown` handler used by jqGrid. You need just call of `saveRow` in case of `e.keyCode === 13`. The required `rowid` you can either get from the outer scope (if you do this inside of `oneditfunc`) or to get it from `e.target`: `$(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id")`.

One more option: you can add some class like `jqgrid-new-row` (it's the class used by [addRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#addrow) method) to the row (`<tr>`) directly after call of `addRowData` (`$("#" + dataIds[dataIds.length - 1]).addClass("jqgrid-new-row")`). You should add `afterrestorefunc` callback to `editRow` which you call. Inside of the `afterrestorefunc` you can test whether the row has `jqgrid-new-row` class and call `delRowData` row in the case. **By the way if you add the class with `jqgrid-new-row` name (or to use `addRow` instead of `addRowData`) then deleting of canceled row will be done automatically by `restoreRow`** (see [the code fragment](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.7.0/js/grid.inlinedit.js#L422-L427)).

You can even do this unconditionally without any tests for the class `jqgrid-new-row` if the above code work *only* in case of editing of new added row. So the call of `editRow` could be like below

```js
return _this.table.jqGrid("editRow", dataIds[dataIds.length - 1], {
    keys: true,
    url: "clientArray",
    aftersavefunc: function(rowId) {
        return retypeColumnValues.call(table, rowId);
    },
    afterrestorefunc: function(rowId) {
        _this.table.jqGrid("delRowData", rowId); // delete after cancel editing
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Solution was very easy :) I added only `afterrestorefunc` with delete newly added row without testing of class `jqgrid-new-row`, because you have right that mentioned code works only in case editing of newly added row. I tried to use `addRow` instead of `addRowData`, but it was problem. The row was added on first place in grid.