# How to display message on cancel of jqgrid inline edit?

Tags: jqgrid, inline-editing, free-jqgrid

I am using jqgrid inline edit funcationality. I want to display message to user, if user has made changes in edit mode and clicked on cancel button instead of save. 
How to achieve this?

I tried using beforeCancelRow by referring this post
[jqgrid - Add new row and disable restoreRow function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27704402/jqgrid-add-new-row-and-disable-restorerow-function)
but it gives me error as : Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'sr' is undefined

JqGrid version : Jqgrid free 4.6.0. and formatter: 'actions' is used for inline editing.

Comment: First of all you should specify 1) which fork of jqGrid (old jqGrid in version <=4.7, [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) or [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334)) and in which version you use 2) in which form you use inline editing: do you use `inlineNav` or `formatter: "actions"`. You write about "cancel button" which can be in the same line in case of usage `formatter: "actions"` or to be on the navigator bar in case of usage `inlineNav`. The name `sr` from the error message shows that you use min version instead of src required for troubleshooting.

Comment: Hi Oleg, 1) I am using free jqGrid  4.6.0. 2) i have used formatter: 'actions' for inline editing. Cancel button is present in every row of grid.